# How to change datetime system timezone to other zones in SQL Query using CONVERT_TZ() SQL Function

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I have two times timeA & timeB stored in database, I am using SQL Query to extract data from DB as:

```
SELECT ID, timeA, timeB, CREATED_AT, IS_ACTIVE 
FROM datatable 
WHERE IS_ACTIVE = TRUE AND NOW() >= timeA AND NOW() <= timeB;
```

which is working fine!

Now due to timezone changes, I need to have data compared in US/EASTERN timezone, I have found CONVERT_TZ() method to change the system time in any other timezone by using it as

```
CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'SYSTEM', 'US/EASTERN')
```

By applying CONVERT_TZ() function, SQL Query becomes:

```
SELECT ID, timeA, timeB, CREATED_AT, IS_ACTIVE 
FROM datatable 
WHERE IS_ACTIVE = TRUE AND CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'SYSTEM', 'US/EASTERN') >= timeA AND CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'SYSTEM', 'US/EASTERN') <= timeB;
```

and it is not working (giving null as result).

kindly suggest if I am doing anything wrong or other ways if possible to do this.

Comment: Does you import timezones table data? Specifying non-existent timezone name will give NULL. Check `select * from mysql.time_zone_name where name='US/EASTERN';` - you must obtain a record with `Time_zone_id=582`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! do the time_zone_id will be used as a reference in CONVERT_TZ() function?

Comment: *do the time_zone_id will be used as a reference in CONVERT_TZ() function?* No. It is service data, server uses it while performing timezone convertion implicitly. But by default system tables relative to timezone support are empty and must be filled with data separately.

Comment: @Akina I got the thing you are saying, but due to lack of permissions, I am unable to see the system level tables data, is there any other way?

Comment: Simply check the code from [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz).

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html